# JTree selection

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTree which is 5 level deep, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 levels. I am interested in level 1's informaton, value or index. is it possible to immediately get level 1' information whenever the selection is below level 1?

Comment: Hmm... are you trying to find the level 1 node *above* the selected item?

Comment: Maybe I described it wrong. I was thinking level 0 is root and level 4 is leaf. what I need is if user's selection is on level 2, 3 or 4, I want get corresponding level 1's info immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the selected level 1 node use the method

```
JTree.getSelectionPath()
```

To get the selected TreePath then check if the TreePath returned has at least 2 elements (first is the root, second the selected level 1 node) with

```
TreePath.getPathCount()

 If the return>= 2 then use 

TreePath.getPathComponent(1) 

to get the selected level 1 node. (0 index is the root)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your level 1 nodes are static, you can just keep a reference to them in your tree class. That'll give you a direct way to access those nodes, and you'll have the derived class information available assuming you've used one.

There's also `DefaultTreeModel.getChild(...)` which would let you get a node by its index under the root node.

If you're trying to go "up" the tree to the level 1 node, you could try `getPathToRoot` on the tree model. The level 1 node (just under root) would be `result[1]`.

Comment: @user131273 You should definitely not be keeping static references to tree nodes. If you use the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` or a similar implementation where nodes have references to children nodes, then ALL of your tree instances will be operating on the same nodes and you'll end up with nodes from tree A mixed in with nodes in tree B. Just FYI.

Comment: @Shakedown Yeah, that'd be true. I meant static as in the English word meaning "not going to change", not in the Java language sense of "shared across all instances."  Bad word choice on my part! :-)